# Azure Deploy multiple projects on single web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, subdomain, webdeploy, azure-webapps

I have three different projects, I have to deploy these projects under single web app with different sub domains. I already purchased the custom domain. To deploy these project I have created three directories.
[image]

I have also setup the virtual directories in the app settings.

[image]

The domains are also set
[image]

And I deploy the web part like this.

[image]

Now when I'm trying to access the web sub domain its showing me the default azure page
[image]

How can I access the projects on the basis of sub domains.

Comment: try to access URL`https://web.example.com/web`, what's the result?

Comment: Yea. thats working but can't I just get it through `https://web.example.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got an idea from Nancy comment. So you just have to update the virtual applications and the directories as follows.

[image]

Now I can access the web using `https://web.example.com/` Thanks @Nancy.